# Google Play: переход с платной на In-app Billing

Tags: android, google-play, android-billing

Здравствуйте. Существует уже опубликованное приложение как две версии (платная и бесплатная) в Google Play. Понадобилось сделать так, чтобы в итоге осталось одно приложение с In-app Billing, то есть пользователь бы видел в Google Play только одно приложение, скачивал его как бесплатное и в случае, если захотел дополнительных функций, приобрел бы их через внутреннюю покупку, тем самым получив версию приложение с доступом ко всем функциям.

Есть мысль, что проект с платной версией сделать бесплатную и обновить приложение уже с внутренней покупкой, но я не знаю, если пользователь решил переустановить приложение, у него будет возможность получить доступ к расширенным функциям и повторно не платить деньги?

Вопрос: как лучше всего сделать переход с двух проектов приложения (бесплатная и платная) на один проект приложения с внутренней покупкой?
И хотелось бы (если это вообще возможно), чтобы те пользователи, которые купили до этого приложение, имели возможность восстановить доступ ко всем функциям, не заплатив повторно деньги.

Answer (score 2):

Выпустите обновление для платной версии, которое где-нибудь на телефоне оставит XML или любой другой файл указывающий на то, что это платная версия. Затем ждите когда максимальное кол-во устройств с платной версией обновится. Затем просто удаляйте платную версию. Бесплатную же обновите добавив In-app Billing и bool free которая по умолчанию true, сделайте проверку на наличие файла, который мы создавали ранее и если он есть, то bool free изменяем на false и удаляем файл. Далее думаю всё понятно.

Comment: Автор вопроса хочет оставить только платное, но с переводом его в статус бесплатного с подключением In-app Billing. Мою правку ответа завернули и рекомендовали написать её здесь.
[далее после временной платной версии]
Теперь обновите платную версию, добавив In-app Billing и bool free, которая по умолчанию true. Сделайте проверку на наличие файла, который мы создавали ранее, и если он есть, то bool free изменяем на false и удаляем файл.
Выпускаете в Play эту обновлённую платную версию и затем переводите приложение в статус бесплатного. А изначально бесплатную версию удаляете из Play.